# How should I handle an automated build that conflicts with a check-in policy?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, build-automation

Some of our TFS users have some automated builds that are updating version numbers in a tree that is covered by a check-in policy. The workarounds so far are for the automated build to tag the check-in with a dummy workitem or to override the policy. Is there any better way to handle this? If it means hooking up a more advanced check-in policy implementation we'll probably just stick with one of the workarounds described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On checkin, make sure the /override command line switch is being set.  That will override any policy that is in place.